# Perform SQL statement after each DELETE

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb, jooq

Is there a way to make jOOQ perform a SQL statement (in my case a `CHECKPOINT`) after each `DELETE`?

Ideally there would also be a way to specify the tables that this happens for.

The RDBMS I'm using (HSQLDB) doesn't allow this statement inside a trigger, otherwise I would have done it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make jOOQ perform a SQL statement (in my case a CHECKPOINT) after each DELETE?

The easiest way forward would be to use an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) which checks whether the current statement is a `DELETE` statement. You can do this:

- Either using a regex on the generated SQL, if you also have plain SQL statements that are not generated using the jOOQ DSL
- Or using an `instanceof Delete` check on [`ExecuteContext.query()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteContext.html#query--) if you're sure that you're only running jOOQ DSL statements.

This is to detect the execution of such a statement. Your follow up statement can be run in different ways, of course.

> Ideally there would also be a way to specify the tables that this happens for.

This is a bit more tricky. You could implement your own [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) that finds all the delete statements on specific tables.

This only works if you use the DSL API, unless you're willing to run a `VisitListener` on a jOOQ query that you [parse](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) based on your plain SQL statements, in case of which you could also do this for arbitrary other statements. Assuming that the parser can parse your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to execute "checkpoint" from within jOOQ using the Execute statement, something like:

```
//create connection

String sql = "use [MyDatabase] checkpoint ";
connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
```

Having said that, why run a checkpoint after each deleted record? If you're worried about the data being written to disc, just run "checkpoint" you iterate through all your delete operations.